# How can I set custom date formats in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I would like all my dates in org-mode to be displayed like `<Mon 24-Aug 2015>`. I found a piece of code that addresses the problem

```
(setq-default org-display-custom-times t)
(setq org-time-stamp-custom-formats '("<%b %e, %Y>" . "<%b %e, %Y %H:%M>"))
```

but I'm not sure how to edit it to fit my needs. Any ideas?

Comment: `org-mode` recommends placing overlays over the date, rather than changing the date format itself.  http://orgmode.org/manual/Custom-time-format.html  -- `C-c C-x C-t` aka `(org-toggle-time-stamp-overlays)`  The overlays are controlled with the variables set forth in the question above.  See the comment of Dan below for additional details regarding formatting the date overlay.

Comment: Have a look at the docstring for `format-time-string`, which will explain your options for the various formatting strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
(setq-default org-display-custom-times t)
(setq org-time-stamp-custom-formats '("<%a %e-%b %Y>" . "<%a %e-%b %Y %H:%M>"))
```

Will produce:

```
<2020-09-14 Mon>
```

and

```
 <2020-09-14 Mon 16:02>
```